# firestore array_contains condition is ignored (python)

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I am using python (3.11) to query google firestore db
specifically 'array_contains' condition, but it just ignores it and does not do any filtering

Here is my code:

```
tails_ref = db_ref.collection('tails')
tails_ref.where('visible_to', 'array_contains', 'red')
docs = tails_ref.stream()
for doc in docs:
    print(f"{doc.id} => {doc.to_dict()}")
```

as a result I am getting whole collection:

```
0NAjJEgWWZqX9n5PALTp => {..., 'visible_to': ['red', 'blue'], ...}
1KHfzw9zcgISxGKtaWA0 => {..., 'visible_to': ['blue'], ...}
1d3YWvDileK3105UXRTd => {..., 'visible_to': [], ...}
5xaQsc4tD2SSco6g3E8F => {..., 'visible_to': ['red'], ...}
```

I expect to see only docs with value 'red' in 'visible_to' array
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

after posting a question I found a mistake: I need to re-assign reference with condition:

```
tails_ref = tails_ref.where('visible_to', 'array_contains', 'red')
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
tails_ref = tails_ref.where('visible_to', 'array_contains', 'red')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When answering a question, it's usually a good idea to explain the answer out instead of just leaving a code snippet. Also, don't forget to format it correctly with code fences! Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for more info.